# XPath query: why no results?

Tags: xml, string, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<pets>
    <dog name="Rupert" color="grey"/>
    <dog name="Ralph" color="brown"/>
    <cat name="Marvin the Cat" color="white"/>
    <cat name="Garfield the Cat" color="orange"/>
    <cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
    <cat name="Fluffy" color="black"/>
</pets>
```

I have the following XPath query:

```
//cat[@*[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')] = 'marvin the cat']
```

But it returns no results. I'm trying to translate the value of the `@*` to be lower case.

**What I am looking for is a result that "matches whole word" while being case insensitive. How can I change this query to achieve the result I want?**

Note: I had wanted to use the XPath 2.0 `matches` function, but I just found out I'm limited to XPath 1.0. Therefore I need a workaround!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You prematurely ended the predicate. Try this:

```
//cat[@*[translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'marvin the cat']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding translating all attributes....

```
//cat[translate(@name, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'marvin the cat']
```